# Почему при создании сервера выдается ошибка throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event?

Tags: node.js

При запуске проверки работы сервера выдается ошибка, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код

```js
const http = require('http');
const PORT = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   console.log('Server request');
});

server.listen(PORT, 'localshost', (error) => {
   error ? console.log(error) : console.log('listening port ${PORT}');
});
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас опечатка: `localshost` вместо `localhost`

Имени `localshost` компьютер не знает - отсюда и ошибка